# TextView to send email when clicked

Tags: android

I have a TextView with android:autoLink="email".

If I put my email address in there then a link appears that I can click.

How do I have different text appear (for example 'Send Feedback') instead of the email address but still behave the same when clicked?

Thanks

Answer (score 67, accepted):

To achieve what I wanted required a different approach:

```
TextView feedback = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewSendFeedback);
feedback.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"mailto:ask@me.it\">Send Feedback</a>"));
feedback.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

This basically places HTML in the TextView so I get a link saying 'Send Feedback' but clicking it opens the default email application.

**Word of warning:** *Trying this in the emulator didn't initially work for me, saying it was unsupported. This was just because I didn't have an email account setup. Setting one up in the emulator made the link work as I wanted.*

Comment: One thing to watch out for, is that this won't work if you set the         android:autoLink to "all". It probably doesn't work if you set android:autoLink to anything except "none", but I haven't tested that.

Comment: If you store the string in a string resource you need to replace the left angle bracket with &lt;

Comment: If there is no any mail app it will crash your app: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54982981/mailto-crashes-an-app-if-user-doesnt-have-mail-app

Comment: I believe my warning at the bottom of my own answer states this already, but thanks.

Answer (score 54):

You can use both links and email if you set the following param in the TextView

```
android:autoLink="web|email"
```

the links will be opened in the browser and the mails will be sent by the default mail client

Comment: Does it handle exceptions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54982981/mailto-crashes-an-app-if-user-doesnt-have-mail-app

Answer (score 36):

Another simple way in layout:

```
...
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTelefone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sobre_telefone"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:autoLink="phone" />
...    

...
<string name="sobre_telefone">Contato: (45) 9145-0000</string>
}
```

Read more here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:autoLink

Comment: This is in fact the best solution if you just need basic support for website and email address linking. For those confused with the answer, just check the provided `autoLink` property link.

Comment: To change the color of the link `textColorLink` needs to be used.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to create a button and inside your onClickListener() pull an email from maybe R.string.email.

Comment: That is a very good suggestion that I never considered! I may actually use that, even though I have found the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Fro the Strings From `strings.xml` :

```
<string name="your_string"><![CDATA[ contact us at <a href=\"mailto:recipient@mail.com\">recipient@mail.com</a> for more help.]]></string>


tvObject.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.your_string)));
tvObject.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```