# Android TextView link email containing apostrophes

Tags: android, textview, apostrophe

I have a TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:text="Contact details go here"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvContactDetails"
    android:autoLink="email" />
```

I then put an e-mail address in (I'm using Monodroid, but it doesn't really make any difference here):

```
TextView tvContactDetails = FindViewById(Resource.Id.tvContactDetails)
tvContactDetails.Text = sEmail;
```

If I give it an e-mail address like joe@bloggs.com it's fine.  But when I give it kevin.o'donnel@abc.com it only hyperlinks donnel@abc.com.  How can I get it to recognise apostrophes as part of the e-mail address?

Comment: You can first try with: `tvContactDetails.setText(sEmail);`

Comment: put back slash "\" before apostrophes.

Comment: i posted same answer so +1

Answer (score 0):

After a while of searching and trying things I found a solution which worked for me at:

[TextView to send email when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682859/textview-to-send-email-when-clicked)

TextView now looks like this:

```
<TextView
    android:text="Contact details go here"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvContactDetails"/>
(autoLink taken out)
```

The code now looks like this:

```
TextView tvContactDetails = FindViewById(Resource.Id.tvContactDetails)
string sHtmlEmail = "<a href=\"mailto:" + sEmail + "\">" + sEmail + "</a>";
tvContactDetails.TextFormatted = Html.FromHtml(sHtmlEmail);
tvContactDetails.MovementMethod = Android.Text.Method.LinkMovementMethod.Instance;
```

Thanks for the suggestions though.