# mailto crashes an app if user doesn't have mail app

Tags: android

Is it possible to catch this exception when using `mailto:` in `TextView's` text?

> Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException No Activity
>   found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   dat=mailto:xxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx (has extras) }
>   android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent

```
<string name="about_text"><![CDATA[
Support: <a href="mailto:test@gmail.com">test@gmail.com</a>
]]></string>
```

Comment: Post more information please.

Comment: @RyanGodlonton-Shaw which additional information do you need?

Comment: @RyanGodlonton-Shaw I use `mailto` in `TextView` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682859/textview-to-send-email-when-clicked?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Is this layout in an activity?

Comment: The exception says that the emulator you are testing on is not having any mail app to handle mail intent. Try using a real device!

Comment: @Gourav read carefully, it's what I said. And no one mentioned emulator

Answer (score 0):

you can handle this error while try to execute it like this:

```
try {
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "your error message" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: I don't use `startActivity`, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682859/textview-to-send-email-when-clicked?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can still use this to catch the exception, regardless of how it gets thrown, whether through `startActivity` or otherwise..

```
try {
    //  Your Code Here
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Mail client not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```